# Is there a name for $x/x$ in a non-unital algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, nonassociative-algebras

I'm looking into an algebraic structure on $\mathbb{R}^3$ in which multiplication is defined (commutative), as well as division. That is, if $a\cdot b = c$, then $c/b=a$, if $c$ and the modulus of $b$ are non-zero. If $x=(a,0,0)$ or anything else with two zeros, then $x/x=x/a$, which means $(1,0,0)$ acts as a sort of "relative identity" for elements of the form $(a,0,0)$.

However, there is no "universal" multiplicative identity. In general, $x/x$ just refers to the unique element $z\in\mathbb{R}^3$ for which $x\cdot z=x$ (if the modulus of $x$ is non-zero), but $x/x$ is not necessarily equal to $y/y$. Although it may be worth noting that the sum of the components of $x/x$ is generally $1$. See comments for a more precise definition of this system.

> Is there standard algebra terminology to refer to the value of $x/x$, when there is no multiplicative identity?

Also, are there other terms here that I should be describing differently (since I'm not studying this topic in any sort of structured way and having words for things has been a challenge).

Comment: How do you define $x/x$ *in general* to begin with?

Comment: As $x\cdot x^{-1}$, where $(a,b,c)^{-1}=\tfrac{(a^2-bc,b^2-ca,c^2-ab)}{a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc}$. I found this expression using the inverse of a matrix representation of these numbers.

Also, $(a,b,c)\cdot(x,y,z) = (ax+bz+cy,az+by+cx,ay+bx+cz)$.

Comment: Of course $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc$ can be zero with $(a,b,c)\ne(0,0,0)$.

Comment: That value is what I'm calling the modulus of $(a,b,c)$, and I'm just calling it that because it seems to have similar properties to the modulus of the split-complex numbers. The only other case I'm aware of in which that expression can be zero is when $a=b=c$.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the modulus will be $0$ whenever $a=b=c$ or $a+b+c=0$.

Answer (score 3):

Commenting more extensively on your structure. The goal is to make some of its properties possibly a bit more transparent. Not sure I succeed, and I'm not really answering the question either :-(

The space $A=\Bbb{R}^3$ is a direct sum of two subspaces, namely
$$
I_1=\{(a,a,a)\mid a\in\Bbb{R}\}
$$
and
$$
I_2=\{(a,b,c)\mid a+b+c=0\}.
$$
Both $I_1$ and $I_2$ are "ideals" of $A$ in the sense that for all $u\in A$ we have
$ui_1\in I_1$ for all $i_1\in I_1$, and $ui_2\in I_2$ for all $i_2\in I_2$. Consequently
$i_1i_2=0_A$ for all $i_1\in I_1, i_2\in I_2$. We can thus conclude that $A\cong I_1\oplus I_2$ also as algebras.

Here $I_1$ is isomorphic with the field $\Bbb{R}$. This is because we easily see that
$(a,a,a)(b,b,b)=(3ab,3ab,3ab)$, meaning that $\phi:\Bbb{R}\to I_1$,
$$\phi(t)=(\frac t3,\frac t3,\frac t3)$$
is an isomorphism.

In $I_2$ let's single out the elements $e=\dfrac13(2,-1,-1)$ and $v=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}(0,1,-1)$. Your product (denoting it $\star$) formula shows that
$$
\begin{aligned}
e\star e&=\dfrac19(6,-3,-3)&=&&e,\\
e\star v&=\dfrac1{3\sqrt3}(0,-3,3)&=&&-v,\\
v\star v&=\dfrac13(-2,1,1)&=&&-e,
\end{aligned}
$$
showing that the basis $\{e,v\}$ is simple for calculations. For all real numbers $a,b,c,d$ we have
$$
(ae+bv)\star(ce+dv)=(ac-bd)e-(ad+bc)v.
$$
In other words, if we equate the complex number $z=x+yi$ with $xe+yv\in I_2$, your product looks like
$$
z_1\star z_2=\overline{z_1z_2};
$$
the usual complex multiplication followed by complex conjugation.

> So it looks like your algebra is isomorphic to $\Bbb{R}\times\Bbb{C}$ with a product defined like
>   $$(x_1,z_1)\star(x_2,z_2)=(x_1x_2,\overline{z_1z_2}).$$

I don't recall seeing anything like this. Your algebra is non-associative for sure:
$$
e\star(v\star v)=e\star(-e)=-e,$$
but
$$
(e\star v)\star v=(-v)\star v=e.
$$

Anyway, the connection to complex multiplication makes it obvious that also in the "ideal" $I_2$ we have "unique division" for the property follows from that of the arithmetic of complex numbers. Let us denote by $\psi:I_2\to\Bbb{C}$ the
linear isomorphism
$$\psi(xe+yv)=x+iy.$$
If $u_1,u_2,u_3\in I_2$ are arbitrary, $u_2\neq0$, and $z_i=\psi(u_i), i=1,2,3$ are the corresponding complex numbers, then the equation
$$
u_2\star u_3=u_1
$$
is equivalent to the equation of complex numbers
$$
\overline{z_2z_3}=z_1,
$$
which has 
$$
z_3=\frac{\overline{z_1}}{z_2}
$$
as its unique solution. Thus the element
$$
u_3=\psi^{-1}\left(\frac{\overline{\psi(u_1)}}{\psi(u_2)}\right)
$$
is the only solution of the equation $u_2\star u_3=u_1$ in $I_2$, and
"entitled" to be called $u_1/u_2$.

In particular, for an arbitrary element $x=t+u\in A$ such that $t\in I_1$ and
$u\in I_2$ are both non-zero, we have
$$
\frac x x=\phi(1)+\psi^{-1}\left(\frac{\overline{\psi(u)}}{\psi(u)}\right).
$$
Here $z(u):=\overline{\psi(u))}/\psi(u)$ is on the unit circle, so 
$z(u)=\cos\alpha+i\sin\alpha$ for some $\alpha$ depending on $u$. Pulling it all back to the original notation of $A$, the elements $x/x$ all have the form
$$
\begin{aligned}
\phi(1)+\psi^{-1}(z(u))&=(\frac13,\frac13,\frac13)+\cos\alpha e+\sin\alpha v\\
&=\frac13(1+2\cos\alpha,1-\cos\alpha+\sqrt3\sin\alpha,1-\cos\alpha+\sqrt3\sin\alpha)\\
&=\frac13\left(1+2\cos\alpha,1+2\cos(\alpha-2\pi/3),1+2\cos(\alpha+2\pi/3)\right).
\end{aligned}
$$
If $x$ happens to be an element of either $I_1$ or $I_2$, then $x/x$ is not unique
(=not well-defined).

This gives us the following characterization:

> The elements of the form $x/x$ consist exactly of the points $(a,b,c)\in\Bbb{R}^3$ on the intersection of the plane $a+b+c=1$ and the unit sphere
>   $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks! This has made a few important quantities clearer to me, but I'm still on my way to understanding how to interpret the product geometrically. Is there a way I can better define division on these numbers, so that it also works for $I_2$, or would it just be a kind of complex division constrained to that ideal only? It's easy enough to show why certain divisions (namely, by elements of the form $(a,a,a)$ or $(x,y,-x-y)$) have an infinite number of solutions, but does that not apply when dividing elements within the ideal(s)?

Comment: @bjshnog I added a bit about what kind of elements appear as quotients $x/x$ in $A$. Hopefully I didn't goof any of this up. If you find something that doesn't match with this data, please comment. Easy to make errors here, but looking for one without a numerical example is like... needle in a haystack.

Comment: I see, thanks. This more or less confirms what I'd found using matrices. These "tri-numbers", as I'm calling them, can be represented as matrices: $(a,b,c)\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}a&b&c\\c&a&b\\b&c&a\end{pmatrix}$. The (tri) product corresponds to the transpose of the matrix product, which seems to match the complex conjugate part of your description. I found the multiplicative inverse of each of the elements not in $I_1$ or $I_2$ using the inverse transpose of the matrix form, which only exists when $a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc\neq0$, which is equivalent to $a+b+c\neq0\wedge\neg(a=b=c)$.

Comment: I would like to make the note that the unit sphere isn't very meaningful in the context of these numbers, so much as the "unit cylinder" which is the set of elements with a Euclidean distance of $\sqrt{2/3}$ from the "pole", $a=b=c$. The product of any two elements both in either the unit cylinder or unit plane will also be in that unit set.

Comment: Also, dividing some element by another element with the same sum of components will produce an element in the unit plane, while dividing some element by another element the same distance from the pole will produce an element in the unit cylinder. Combining both of these, you can conclude that $x/x$ will always be on the intersection of the unit plane and unit cylinder, given an $x$ with non-zero "modulus".